# How can I prevent Backbones save method from trying to update every model?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am creating a crud web app with backbone. I am writing the functionality to update a resource (PUT). I am trying to achieve this by fetching a models properties from the server (see the SubscriberView) and on successfully fetching the resource to instantiate a SubscriberEditView whereby the newly fetched model is passed.
So far this works as expected; SubscriberEditView renders an html form which is populated with the model instance properties.
When I enter a new login value into the form I can trigger the update function which successfully makes a PUT request to the server resource and updates the model instance as expected.
However, the problem is that when I then repeat this process with another model instance the PUT request is made against the curent model AND the previously instantiated model.
Is the reason for this because I now have two instances of SubscriberEditView? Or is it something else that I have missed/misunderstood.

Please see below the described code.

```js
// The view for a single subscriber
var SubscriberView = Backbone.View.extend({
 tagName: 'tr',
 template: _.template($('#subscribers-tmpl').html()),
 initialize: function() {
  this.listenTo(this.model, 'destroy', this.remove);
 },
 render: function() {  
  var html = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
  this.$el.html(html);
  return this;
 },
    events: {
        'click .remove': 'onRemove',
        'click .edit-subscriber': 'editSubscriber',
    },
    editSubscriber: function() {   
     var getSubscriberModel = this.model.set('id', this.model.attributes.id, {silent:true})
     getSubscriberModel.fetch({
      success: function (model, response) {
       $('#addSubscriber').fadeOut();
       new SubscriberEditView({model:model});     
      },
      error: function (response) {
       console.log('There was an error');
      }
     });
    },
    onRemove: function() {
        this.model.destroy();
    }    
});

// The edit view
var SubscriberEditView = Backbone.View.extend({
 tagName: 'div',
 el: '#updateSubscriber',
 template: _.template($('#subscriberEdit-tmpl').html()),
 initialize: function() {
  this.model.on('sync', this.render, this);
 },
 events: {
  'click #close': 'cancel',
  'click .save-subscriber': 'update'
 },
 update: function() {
  var $login = this.$('#login');
  this.model.save({
   login: $login.val(),
  },
        { 
   dataType: 'text',
   success: function (model, response, options) {
    console.log('success');
     
        },
   error: function (model, response, options) {
    console.log('error');
        }
        });
 },
 cancel: function() {
  $('#addSubscriber').fadeIn();
  $('#editInner').fadeOut();
 },
 render: function() {
  var html = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
  this.$el.html(html);
 }, 
});
```

If anyone could help then that would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: Why `options.data = JSON.stringify(attrs);
     options.contentType = "application/json";`?

Comment: What's the point of `var getSubscriberModel = this.model.set('id', this.model.attributes.id, {silent:true})`?

Comment: @T J oops...there is no purpose..I left it there by accident

Comment: Please clean up the code and create a [mcve]. Remove all the code that is not related to the problem.

Comment: As far as I know, it's better to use PATCH request to update with Backbone. I don't know if that's the issue though.

Comment: Along the lines of @ManuelHoffmann, this is from the Backbone docs:
If instead, you'd only like the changed attributes to be sent to the server, call model.save(attrs, {patch: true}). You'll get an HTTP PATCH request to the server with just the passed-in attributes.
So if your backend works with PATCHs for those attrs, backbone already has the functionality you are trying to get with your overwrite. [Backbone model-save](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save)

Comment: @TJ I have updated my question to hopefully make things clearer and have included only the relevant code. Thanks for your responses so far.

Comment: @jacob.m I don't believe this is the issue, as I am successfully making a PUT request as expected. The issue is that I appear to be making requests against multiple instances of my model...not just a single instance. Many thanks.

Comment: @James_101 agreed its not the problem, just figured might be useful. Check and see if your views are all listening to the edit event (in your event maybe console.log("View's model updating",this.cid); (if this is the view).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `el: '#updateSubscriber',`. All your view instances are pointing to same element to which events are delegated. So clicking on any of the `.save-subscriber` will trigger update for all the view instances. You should not specify `el` for a view that is going to have more than one instance.

Comment: Ok, that seems like I've made an obvious mistake there, but if I am not specifying an [el] then how does my view template get rendered inside the DOM?

Comment: @James_101 Backbone creates an element as `el` for each instance unless you specify `el`. So you can append the template into this element and append it to DOM

Comment: @T J Thanks for your help.